# How to turn off the message "`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'"

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

When I use `ggplot` and when I use `stat_smooth()` I get automatic messages like this:

> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x

The problem is I use RMarkdown to build a PDF and I want to show some plots there. This message will be shown there like this:
[image]

How can I turn this message off? Or any way to not show it on the PDF with the plots.

Comment: I suggest `invisible(geom_smooth())`, `invisible()` supress console output

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez I tried `invisible(stat_smooth())` but it is still there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If rmarkdown is being used then making use of chunk options can be useful. So in your chunk set it like this:

`{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}`

You can turn off warnings and messages for the whole document by running this code in the first chunk:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
```
````

Comment: I think the doesn't work because the thing that prints is a "message", not a "warning" ([see here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/12e61dfcf9151c2094536294a8ef42ddffdca9ef/R/stat-smooth.r#L118)) So you need to turn off messages for that chunk so use `{r message=FALSE}`

Answer (score 15):

If you replicate this example in RMarkdown, do you still get the error?

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 50)),
                 week = rep(1:50, 3),
                 rate = c(round(700 - rnorm(50, 100, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0)))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week,
             y = rate,
             group = group,
             lty = group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

** This prints the warning/info **

Then try changing the final line:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 50)),
                 week = rep(1:50, 3),
                 rate = c(round(700 - rnorm(50, 100, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0),
                          round(1000 - rnorm(50, 200, 10) - 1:50 * 2, 0)))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week,
             y = rate,
             group = group,
             lty = group)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess")
```

** No warning/info **

Answer (score 0):

This 'message' is not a message as far as R markdown is concerned, nor is it a warning.
Check out this link for a resolution to this problem.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/need-help-with-error-when-running-geom-smooth-using-formula-y-x/92890

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32197343)